# Java Processes are getting aborted because of fatal Error has detected by JRE

Tags: java, solaris, fatal-error

```
Below are the logs:

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0xffffffff77163754, pid=14909, tid=2110955
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode solaris-sparc compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.1+0x63754]# [ timer expired, abort... ]
Abort
```

It is intermittent issue not so frequent.I have read so many blogs claimed its a bug. if it is then please tell in which version it is fixed.Current version of java is 1.7.0_80

Any Help will be lauded guys 
   Thanks

Comment: This indicates a bug in the JVM or in some native code.

Comment: Do you have a core file?  What's mapped at address `0xffffffff77163754`?  You can run `pmap core` to find out.  If you don't have a core file, run `pmap PID`, where `PID` is the process ID of the Java process that fails in this manner.

Comment: I have run both the commands given by you but Core file is not present itself . output of the commands :- **pmap: cannot examine core: no such process or core file.**

Comment: Since its solaris, Core files won't be created,

Comment: @priyamsingh *Since its solaris, Core files won't be created.*  What makes you say that?  That's not true at all.  Try `man coreadm`.